# Convert device path starting with \\?\ to Path

Tags: java, hid

I want to read and write data to a HID device in a java program.

The device's path, in Windows, is formatted like so:
`\\?\HID#VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX#...#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`. The `\\?\` prefix is a [special windows namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces).
I can use `RandomAccessFile` to open the device with no problem, because the constructor requires a `String`.
However, when i try to convert it to a `Path`, this happens:

```
Path.of("\\\\?\\HID#VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX#...#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}");

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal character [?] in path at index 2: \\?\HID#VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX#...#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.nextSlash(WindowsPathParser.java:212)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at ...
```

Since i want to use the `AsynchronousFileChannel` class, i have to convert it to a `Path` first. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `\\?\` with `\\.\` seems to do the trick:

```
String rawPath = "\\\\?\\HID#VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX#...#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
var newPath = Path.of(rawPath.replace("\\\\?\\", "\\\\.\\");
```

Comment: Please add your note as an update to your question, don't ask and answer by yourself

Comment: @Mori - no: posting a self-answer is allowed, and [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). There is nothing wrong with doing so.